# Concatenated get requests API call in react

Tags: reactjs

This get request - http://localhost:7000/api/search/gender/Female results in

```
    {
    "id": 32,
    "email": "no"
},
```

Backend code:

```
const app = require('express').Router(),
  db = require('../../../config/db'),
  User = require('../../../config/User')

app.get('/search/:type/:value', async (req, res) => {
  const { type, value } = req.params

module.exports = app
```

Comment: Are you asking how to filter all the responses or how to make only a single request with those params?

Comment: make a single request with multiple parms will be the best. If that is not possible, filtering would be the last option

Comment: gender, occupation, state, city, email are all columns of the users database in my sql

Comment: Need to configure back end first. For more robust search just read query params at `/api/search` then document what those params would be and do the filtering in your db queries based on those params

Comment: Then url would look something like `/api/search?email=true&gender=female&city=athens` or whatever combination is appropriate for what you need at the time. Using URL API will help build the queries on front end https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: nice.. This got me thinking in an entirely new direction. I have posted my backend code at the bottom of the question. Any suggestions ? If you post an answer I will accept it. You already got me thinking the right way

Comment: Right now I am using app.get('/search/:type/:value' but there must be a better way to configure backend

Comment: The query string params should  be in `req.query`

Comment: problem solved. Your comment helped me solve this. Thanks

Comment: And you didnt even post a single line of code but just the direction you took me in helped immensely

Comment: Glad to hear it. Sounds like you are well on your way

Comment: yes, If you post an answer with the comment above about backend, I will mark accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to set up your back end to read query string params and use those params to do your db filtering so you can make a single request to get whatever filtered data you need

Then your url would look something like:

```
/api/search?email=true&gender=female&city=athens
```

or whatever combination of params you need at the time

You should be able to pass objects to axios and it will serialze the front end params for you or use the URL API and specifically it's searchParams to construct url's